# How to include VCRUNTIME140D.lib in cmake file?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to create a dll file using cmake. I can run my dll file on Windows, but not on a virtual machine or a machine that does not have Visual Studio installed on its system.

so I checked the dll file missing dependecies using the tool. following are the missing dependencies:

**MSVCP140d.dll,
msi.dll,
WS2_32.dll,
VCRUNTIME140D.dll,
ucrtbased.dll**

I have tried to resolve it by adding a few commands to the cmake file to make it work. But the issue remains the same.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MT")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /MTd")


set(CMAKE_MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "MultiThreaded$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Debug>")
```

please help! how should make it work so that my dll is compatible to run on any maching whether it has visual studio install or not?

#vcruntime140.dll

Comment: `VCRUNTIME140D.dll` is a debug version of the VC Runtime. You should'nt need that - you shouldn't deploy a debug build to anywhere but your local machine for debugging. Deploy a release build and you wont have these issues.

Comment: You need to install the vcredist package on the target machine. And always distribute a Release build.